# Rounding borders over collection of divs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Wasn't sure how to title this, but I have an unknown number of child DIVs displayed in two columns using bootstrap. What I'm trying to do is round the corners of the DIVs that lie at the 4 corners of the overall display. Simply enough when I have an even number of elements, but with an odd number then one column will be longer than the other and so 'last-child' would give me the bottom left instead of the bottom right element.

Here's an example. Remove one of the divs and change the commented css to use the even number style and you can see the look I'm going for in both cases.  Is there a way I could apply certain rules if the parent container has an odd or even number of children?

https://jsfiddle.net/v6bm9zjh/1/

```
<div class="row col-md-12 server-container">
  <div class="col-md-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 server">name</div>
</div>
```

.

```
body{margin:10px;}
.server{border:1px solid black;color:white;font-weight:bold;padding:10px}

.server:first-child{border-top-left-radius:7px;}
.server:nth-child(2){border-top-right-radius:7px;}

/* even number of elements */
/*
.server:last-child{border-bottom-right-radius:7px;}
.server:nth-last-child(2){border-bottom-left-radius:7px;}
*/


/* odd number of elements */
.server:last-child{border-bottom-left-radius:7px;border-bottom-right-radius:7px;}
.server:nth-last-child(2){border-bottom-right-radius:7px;}
```

Comment: That wouldn't be able to give the visual effect with an odd number of elements.

Comment: If you have a solution for even number of elements and a solution for odd number of elements, why not use modulus (`n % 2 == 0`) to see whether odd or even and apply the appropriate solution based on the result?

Comment: Could you check your codepen, has it got bootstrap enabled? It’s showing me one column only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have both like below. Simply add another condition to your selector to check for odd or even

```css
.server {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px
}

.server:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
}

.server:nth-child(2) {
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}


/* even number of elements */
.server:nth-child(even):last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

.server:nth-child(odd):nth-last-child(2) {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
}

/* odd number of elements */
.server:nth-child(odd):last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}

.server:nth-child(even):nth-last-child(2) {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row col-md-12 server-container mb-5">
  <div class="col-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-6 server">name</div>
</div>



<div class="row col-md-12 server-container">
  <div class="col-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-6 server">name</div>
  <div class="col-6 server">name</div>
</div>
```